# Python Windows Service - Current Path, Custom Modules, and wrong resolutions

Tags: python, path, yaml, python-3.4, pywin32

I have a working windows service which is referencing a custom schema created in SQLAlchemy. Before moving everything into a seperate module, everything was working just fine in python form, exe form, and msi form.

I have never imported custom modules before. Right now, I am staticly loading the path of the module into the application. And it seems to work just fine.

Now I moved the code out, set up an import did some work, and my config file is failing to load! I can't figure it out!

The static load --

```
`sys.path.insert(0,r"c:\dev\nbc_dps_tools\dashboardtotal\schema")
from NydpsSchema import Computer, Drive, Workgroup
`
```

Seems to get me all the objects I need. Figuring out how to dynamically load the path will be done after I figure out the following pathing problem.

```
service_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath("__file__"))
yaml_file = os.path.join(service_dir, 'configs.yaml')
```

Printing the yaml_file path from above gives me the following path in console, when starting the service

[image]

However, after the service starts (successfully) it quickly dies out. Providing the following error in event viewer.

```
Python could not import the service's module 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\nbc_dps_tools\dashboardtotal\Logon_Service_Live\Logon_Service.py", line 82, in <module>
    stream = open(yaml_file, 'r')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\configs.yaml' 

%2: %3
```

As we see, while installing/starting the service, it resolves properly, gets the config file, and starts. However, once it starts, it appears as if the yaml_file path is resolving to win32 site-package. I tried lots of different pathing styles, nothing seems to work.

The idea is that the path should resolve properly whether run from .py, .exe (or msi)

Thanks for reading, if any additional information is required to help, I can always add more.

EDIT : It appears it is resolving to pythonservice.exe, and not to the script